# How to change this to addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

How to change this to addEventListener?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnChangeCheckbox (checkbox) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                alert ("The check box is checked.");
            }
            else {
                alert ("The check box is not checked.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Toggle the checked state of the following checked box:<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox (this)" id="myCheckbox" />
    <label for="myCheckbox">Sample check box</label>
</body>
```

so far i have tried this but nothing happens.

```
var chkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox');

chkbox.addEventListener ('click',function() { if ( chkbox.checked ) { alert('checked'); } },false);
```

Comment: Just move `<script>` before `</body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
    Toggle the checked state of the following checked box:<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox"  id="myCheckbox" />
    <label for="myCheckbox">Sample check box</label>
<script>
    var chkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox');

    chkbox.addEventListener ('click',
      function() { 
        if ( chkbox.checked ) { 
          alert('checked'); 
        } 
      },false);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/73/

```
Toggle the checked state of the following checked box:<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox (this)" id="myCheckbox" />
<label for="myCheckbox">Sample check box</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox');
    chkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (chkbox.checked) {
            alert ("The check box is checked.");
        }
        else {
            alert ("The check box is not checked.");
        }
    });
</script>
```